# Appropriate pattern for given scenario

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, hierarchy

I am developing .NET wrapper over a service where following entities are present:

- **Root** properties Name, Files, Folders, Items
- **Item** properties Name, methods Create, Rename, Delete
- **File** properties Name, methods Create, Rename, Delete
- **Folder** properties Name, Files, Folders, methods Create, Rename, Delete

As you can see, Root entitiy (which is singleton) can hold some Files, Folders and Items. Items can be held only by Root, the cannot be present in any Folder. At the other hand, Files and Folders can be helt by both Root and Folder entities.

I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to project this scenario into code.

Service.Root is going to be a singleton property, there's probably not much more to it.

Service.Root.Files & Service.Root.Folders - should I make custom collections of File and Folder classes for this purpose? And if yes, should I make it possible to create new instances of File and Folder classes only thru methods on these collections? Or should I allow developer to create File/Folder without explicit reference to Service by making a public constructor for it? I guess not? Because for example renaming a file calls methods on Service that works with network. So should every instance of File, Item & Folder have reference to Service?

This question is probably very messy but I don't know well how to explain that, I'm sorry. Generally, I'm asking if it's a good idea to make custom collection of File/Item/Folder types or if it's better to exposes generic collections. Also, should these exposed collections be readonly and creating new files by calling Service.CreateNewFile() instead of Service.Folders[0].Add(New File()) if you know what I mean.

Thanks for any efford and/or good links discussing such development patterns.

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a little of both to achieve your goal. Exposing the collections as properties will give the user the most flexible and familiar interface. However, taking more control over the collections, exposing them as read-only properties, and then providing methods to add, remove, etc. will give you, the class designer, more control. This may lead to fewer issues as access to the collections only occurs via a limited interface.
Therefore, your trade-off is one of flexibility versus control. Both approaches will work.